# Pygame's window opens than closes immediately, why?

Tags: windows, pygame, pycharm

When i run this on Pycharm it opens than closes immediately. Whereas in the video tutorial it just stays open, why?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("hello")
```

i am using windows os, python version 3.7.2, and pygame 1.9.4

Comment: Welcome! I've formatted (proposal) your question according to the best practices here. Maybe you could also include the link to the tutorial?

Comment: Thank you! here is the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6xMBig-pP4&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-lp3jAExUCewBfMx3UZFkh5

Comment: Pls tell me how he managed to keep the window open if you understood

Comment: This programming part begins at 1: 05 and finishes at 2: 10

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which tutorial you talk about, but if the process that created the window finishes, the window will be closed.

E.g. when you create the window via a python shell, the window will stay open as long as the shell is open.

If you open the window via a script (a file), you need to keep the script from finishing. You do this by creating what is called a main loop and usually looks like this:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()

    win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

    pygame.display.set_caption("hello")

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        win.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Could you pls modify my program, for it to work? I know what is a mainloop i already used it in tkinter, But i don t know how it works in Pygame

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you (and I was following the same tutorial) and i found that if you enclose the whole thing in a while loop (excluding **import pygame**, **pygame.init()** and the variable you use for the while loop) it works quite well.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

Game = True

while Game is True:
    window1 = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
```

I have just started learning Python so this might not be the best way to do it but I hope it helps in some way :)